# How to use existing json schema for properties?

Tags: json, jsonschema

My product json is:

```
{
   "id": 123,
   "variant":{
      "id":123,
      "name":"variant 1" 
    }
}
```

I have json schema for **Variant** object and I need to create schema for **Product** object. How can I use existing variant schema in the product schema?

**Examples**:

Product (not-optimized) schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "id": "http://example.com/scheme/product",
  "type": "object",
  "title": "Product",
  "description": "An explanation about the puropose of this instance described by this schema.",
  "name": "Product",
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "id": "http://example.com/scheme/product/id",
      "type": "integer",
      "title": "Id schema.",
      "description": "An explanation about the puropose of this instance described by this schema.",
      "name": "id"
    },
    "variant": {
      "id": "http://example.com/scheme/product/variant",
      "type": "object",
      "title": "Variant schema.",
      "description": "An explanation about the puropose of this instance described by this schema.",
      "name": "variant",
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "id": "http://example.com/scheme/product/variant/id",
          "type": "integer",
          "title": "Id schema.",
          "description": "An explanation about the puropose of this instance described by this schema.",
          "name": "id"
        },
        "name": {
          "id": "http://example.com/scheme/product/variant/name",
          "type": "string",
          "title": "Name schema.",
          "description": "An explanation about the puropose of this instance described by this schema.",
          "name": "name"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "id",
    "variant"
  ]
}
```

Variant schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "id": "http://example.com/scheme/variant",
  "type": "object",
  "title": "Variant",
  "description": "An explanation about the puropose of this instance described by this schema.",
  "name": "Variant",
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "id": "http://example.com/scheme/variant/id",
      "type": "integer",
      "title": "Id schema.",
      "description": "An explanation about the puropose of this instance described by this schema.",
      "name": "id"
    },
    "name": {
      "id": "http://example.com/scheme/variant/name",
      "type": "string",
      "title": "Name schema.",
      "description": "An explanation about the puropose of this instance described by this schema.",
      "name": "name"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "id",
    "name"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$ref` to the rescue.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "id": "http://example.com/scheme/product",
  "type": "object",
  "title": "Product",
  "description": "An explanation about the puropose of this instance described by this schema.",
  "name": "Product",
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "id": "http://example.com/scheme/product/id",
      "type": "integer",
      "title": "Id schema.",
      "description": "An explanation about the puropose of this instance described by this schema.",
      "name": "id"
    },
    "variant": {
      "$ref": "http://example.com/scheme/product/variant"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "id",
    "variant"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [$ref](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-core.html#anchor30). Providing that your variant schema is defined under the node definitions in the same file, it would be like this:

```
"variant": {"$ref": "#/definitions/variant"}
```